# Static variable in Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I am quite new to `Servlets`. I could not figure out the behaviour the following code.

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

  static int counter = 0;

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
          throws IOException {
      if (counter == 0) {
          httpServletResponse.getWriter().print("Counter = " + counter);
          counter++;
      } else {
          httpServletResponse.getWriter().print("Counter = " + counter);
      }
   }
}
```

When I deploy and run it, the result is "Counter = 1" in the browser. Why did it skip "Counter = 0" and prints direct "Counter = 1"?

Comment: It could be that your browser pre-fetched it. If there's a log, it should show how many times the servlet was actually accessed.

Comment: I couldn't tell you, other than you have something weird in your development environment.  Static primitives are often a terrible idea however in servlets.  Use AtomicInteger for this. `static final counter = new AtomicInteger();`

Comment: @RealSkeptic So when a container pre-fetches, it runs the servlet but throws away the output?

Comment: Which web server did you play?

Comment: The web browser might have sent a HEAD request (counter = 1) then a GET request.

Comment: @RomanC I am using Tomcat.

Comment: @BernhardColby Not surprising, you can try a different web server, then come back and post results and minimal example according SO MCVE,  or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)